# WAS 8.5.5.2 : No spring webapplicationinitializer types detected on classpath

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websphere-8

I have a spring mvc project. I am trying to deploy this project on IBM Websphere 8.5.5.2

I have built a war for the project and deployed it on Websphere using the administrative console

I am using Java based configuration.
I am using AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class for configuration.

But when I deploy the application I get the following based on the console:
 **no spring Webapplicationinitializer types detected on classpath**

And spring initialization is not triggered.

My code is as follows

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.demo" })
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class MyWebInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringWebConfig.class };
    }

}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/qwerty", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome() {

        return "qwerty";

    }

}
```

---

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have logs where you can see Spring initialization? Even setting Spring logging to DEBUG level? That's helped me in the past debugging similar issues.

Comment: Yes, the debugging level is already set. But the dispatcher servlet isn't triggered at all because webApplicationInitializer is not detected

Comment: Is any of the main Spring initialization logged?

Comment: No. Nothing related to Spring initialization is logged

Comment: Wish I could be more help, but I haven't tried this myself. Sounds like some possible causes in general, not specific to WebSphere, are multiple copies of Spring, and missing dependencies (e.g. slf4j). http://stefan-isele.logdown.com/posts/201646 Good luck, hopefully somebody who knows more than me will show up.

Comment: (Also, that's a really old fixpack of WAS 8.5.5. I don't know that would make a difference, but if updating is an option, you might consider it.)

Comment: It feels like something is interfering with what Spring intends to happen automatically: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html. I had a similar situation with JSR 303 validation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45819588/796761 . Maybe some WebSphere classloader quirks...

Answer (score 0):

Just to share my case that may help you.

I deploy springmvc servlet with JSP as front end to IBM WAS 8.5 as well.
I have the same debug info from server but it does not affect the performance.

My internalViewResolver and resourceHandler setting in servlet.xml still works.

```
[21/4/21 11:11:38:003 SGT] 000000a4 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [BP13BWDbPocWeb_war#BP13BWDbPocWeb.war]:.No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
[21/4/21 11:11:38:015 SGT] 000000a4 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [BP13BWDbPocWeb_war#BP13BWDbPocWeb.war]:.Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[21/4/21 11:11:38:016 SGT] 000000a4 ContextLoader I org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess, and I've not tried this, is that you're relying on @Configuration and
@ComponentScan({ "com.demo" }) to have your Spring application scanned for annotations. This won't happen by magic when you're running your application as a war file.

Specifically, from the docs below, you're missing a SpringBootServletInitializer that defines a configure method to tell the supporting container which classes it needs to scan for annotations:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

HTH

Comment: I am using Spring and not spring boot. So I can't use SpringBootServletInitializer

Comment: Did you find solution or not ??